# ImportError : No Module named scapy.all

Tags: python, scapy

I've tried to run this code using Pycharm in VirtualMachine Kali Linux and failed.

How to import scapy? I've also tried adding scapy to *file > settings > ProjectInterpreter* in Pycharm but it still doesn't work.

I'm sure I did install scapy using `pip install scapy`. What's the issue now?

[image: Here the image of my screenshot]

```py
from scapy.all import *
        
def scan(ip):
    scapy.arping(ip)        

scan("10.0.2.1")
```

Comment: `from scapy import *` ?

Comment: Why are you using `scapy.all`?  Did a tutorial tell you to do that?

Comment: @Kishan wont work

Comment: @John Gordon actually tutorial just show `import scapy.all as scapy` but the tutorial was old ,and i just tried all resources/info from google but failed

Comment: @luigigi wont work also

Answer (score 1):

first install the package with `pip install scapy`
just use `import scapy`

or use `from scapy import module_or_function_name`

in your case use `from scapy import arping`

You don't need to use * here

Comment: it is scapy, not scrapy

Comment: Ohh but syntax is same use from scapy import arping

Comment: i did _sudo apt-get install scapy_ in my **virtualmachine kali linux** and shows this.
**[sudo] password for kali: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'python3-scapy' instead of 'scapy'
python3-scapy is already the newest version (2.4.3-3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.**

Comment: This answer is wrong. You do need `scapy.all` or you need to use the sub module name directly...

Comment: install with pip installer. check https://pypi.org/project/scapy

Comment: @Rajat Jog i did git clone https://github.com/secdev/scapy
cd scapy
./run_scapy , what to do next? after i run it,it seems like a applications,i dont know how to use it :O

Comment: go to directory "scapy" using cmd using '''cd scapy''' and the run the command "./run_scapy"

Comment: yeah i did ,after i type  ./run_scapy  it turns out a scapy app,i dont know how to describe it

Comment: I'm assuming you have installed python with "pip" functionality. if yes, go to cmd and simply run the command pip install scapy.

Comment: @Rajat Jog cmd is for window , im running these thing in kali linux virtual machine

Comment: @user126004 Go to terminal and run the same command. I'm also working on linux

Comment: i did `pip install scapy`,after that? what should i do , tried `from scapy import arping` but it turns our **No Module named Scapy**

Answer (score 1):

If someone is having the same issue after Udemy course.
The exception is being thrown when you are trying to use it on python2,
`python3 network_scanner.py` should solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Actually I had this problem and the answer is really easy. First of all you need to see which version of pip do you have. you can try `which pip` and also try with `which pip3`. Next, when you open the terminal and and want to write your code if you have pyhton3 write on the command line '`python3` then `from scapy.all import *` will be okay to use.

Answer (score -1):

The followings work without PyCharm:

```
from scapy.all import *

def scan(ip):
    scapy.layers.l2.arping(ip)

scan("10.0.2.1")
```

or

```
import scapy.all as scapy

def scan(ip):                                                                                                   
    scapy.arping(ip)

scan("10.0.2.1")
```

Just execute in terminal:

```
$ python3 network_scanner.py
```