# Why do I get an error "Import scapy.all could not be resolved"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scapy

Python 2.7.18 64 bits.

Code:

```
import scapy.all as scapy

def scan(ip):
    scapy.arping(ip)

scan("192.168.1.1/24")
```

Error:

```
Import "scapy.all" could not be resolved
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError : No Module named scapy.all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60717543/importerror-no-module-named-scapy-all)

Comment: nope, tried those solutions and nothing :( ( i'm new in python follow a guide in yt )

Comment: What version of scapy do you have installed?

Comment: 2.4.5rc1.dev208

Comment: I fixed it by changing the Python version to 3.9, something similar happened to me with the raw_input and the input

Answer (score 0):

this might be the answer:
using this statement `from scapy.all import *`

Comment: Why does it solve the error?